# How can I find records using regex

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-regexp

I have some products in my table and each product has a unique number. Few examples are given below:

```
H-E223I22A1234  
RW-E123I22B2345  
E223I22A4545
```

Above codes are following below format:

```
(H|RW)- = Optional  
E1|E2... = This will be any series of only 2 characters (Preferably we will follow aplhabet and number)  
23 = This is current last 2 digit of current year  
I = Alphabet representation of current month. In this I = September(09)  
22 = Current date. it will be 01-30|31
A|B = It is Side of production. Will always be either A or B  
1234 = 4 digit random number
```

Now I want to find out all products by series and current month and year. For example, If I want to find product of E2 series of September 2023 then what will be the MySQL query. I was trying to achieve the same with regular expression, but MySQL always return all records. Below is my regular expression:

```
Select * from products where code REGEXP '((H|RW)\-)?(([A-Z]{1}[1-9]{1}){1})(23)(I)(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[A|B](\d*)'
```

Comment: FWIW you can increase readability by deleting all `{1}` - `{1}` is meaningless. Also, just in case there's a misunderstanding, `[A|B]` means a character that is `A`, `|` or `B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can build your regex from the component parts you are interested in. For example, using variables:

```sql
SET @month = 9;
SET @year = 2023;
SET @day = 22;
SET @product = 'E2';
SET @regex = CONCAT('((H|RW)\-)?', @product, RIGHT(@year, 2), SUBSTRING('ABCDEFGHIJKL', @month, 1), @day, '[AB]\\d{4}');
```

This results in

```
((H|RW)-)?E223I22[AB]\d{4}
```

You can then get results by:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE code REGEXP @regex
```

Output for your sample data:

```
code
H-E223I22A1234
E223I22A4545
```

Demo on [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/UELKUFci)

You may want to add start (`^`) and end-of-string (`$`) anchors to the regex if necessary to restrict the match to the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern for matching.

```
(?:H-|RW-)?[A-Z]\d23[A-L]\d\d(?:A|B)\d{4}
```

And, this pattern for capturing.

```
(H-|RW-)?([A-Z]\d)23([A-L])(\d\d)(A|B)(\d{4})
```